# Display latest post from every post type

Tags: wordpress, post

I displayed all the post from all the post type in the page. Now i want to display all the latest post from all the post type. I want only one post from all the post type.

To display all the post from all post type i used the following code.

```
 <?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>array('a','b','c'), 'posts_per_page' => 2)); ?>

              <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="issue-content">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail();} ?>

                  <?php get_template_part( 'content-issues', 'page' ); ?>

                  <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                </div><!--issue-content-->

              <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

i tried with the following code

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>array('a','b','c'), 'posts_per_page' => 1)); ?>
```

i cant get from all the post type. How can i get the latest post from all the post type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multiple `query_posts()`

```
 query_posts('post_type=a&posts_per_page=1'); 
 query_posts('post_type=b&posts_per_page=1');
 query_posts('post_type=c&posts_per_page=1');
```

Comment: it is lengthy method. Is there any way which i used array to short the method.

Comment: This website provides a nice article on ways you can use: http://betterwp.net/9-latest-posts-from-each-post-type/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, [get_posts();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function for getting all posts from every post types.

Comment: There are nice description for using get_posts function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts